# Creating a weird matrix

Tags: matrices

So I'm making a documentation about Coding Theory and I'm almost over, but I'll have to create a matrix and I have no idea how to create this specific one, any help would be appreciated. [image: Matrix]

Comment: Does this help http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236399/matrix-inside-matrix ?

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit of stacking can do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\fboxsep=3ex\relax
G=\left[
  \makebox[12ex]{$I_6$}
  \addstackgap[5pt]{$\vcenter{\hbox{\stackon{\fbox{$S_3$}}{$1~1~1~1~1$}}}$}\,
  \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some eyeballing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
G=
\begin{bmatrix}
\qquad\qquad I_6 \qquad\qquad
&
\begin{array}{@{}|ccccc|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} \\
\hline
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{S_5\vphantom{\Bigg|}}\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
\hline
\end{array}\,
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with [`easybmat`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/easy)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{easybmat}

\begin{document}

\[ 
   G = \left[
       \begin{BMAT}(c){cc}{cc}
            & \begin{BMAT}{ccccc}{c}
                 1&1&1&1&1
              \end{BMAT}\\
        I_6 & \begin{BMAT}[4ex]{|c|}{|c|} 
                 S_5 
              \end{BMAT}\\
       \end{BMAT} 
       \right]
   \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$G = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[columns-width=2mm,right-margin=6pt]
\Block{6-5}{I_6}
& & & & & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
& & & & & \Block[draw]{5-5}{S_5} \\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]