# Golay code G_{24} generator matrix problem

Tags: matrices

I have some difficulties with writing this matrix, can somebody help me out?[image],

Comment: What have you tried so far?  (due to the lines you will need to use the `array` env)

Comment: I was thinking about using tikz package, but i have never used it before and it was hard to make it look like a matrix, not just a simple table. I also found a similar question ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312513/creating-a-weird-matrix ), but had no idea how to make it work for me

Comment: Then the `nicematrix` package is something you need to take a look at.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I will take a break and have a look at it!

Answer (score 2):

[image]Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

    \[ \left(\begin{array}{*{5}{c}|c}
      1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
       & & & & & 0 \\
       & & I_{11} & & & \vdots \\
       & & & & & 0 \\ \hline
      0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
       & & & & & 1 \\
       & & \mkern2mu\overline{\mkern-2muQ}_{11} & & & \vdots \\
       & & & & & 1
    \end{array}\right) \in\mathfrak{M}^{12}_{24} \]%


\end{document} [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

With `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for \mathfrak

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{ccccc|c}[margin,xdots/shorten=4pt]
1 & 1 & \Cdots & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
\Block{3-5}{I_{11}}
  &   &        &   &   & 0 \\
  &   &        &   &   & \Vdots \\
  &   &        &   &   & 0 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & \Cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
\
\Block{3-5}{\overline Q_{11}}
  &   &        &   &   & 1 \\
  &   &        &   &   & \Vdots \\
  &   &        &   &   & 1 
\end{pNiceArray}
\in \mathfrak{M}_{24}^{12}(Z_2)$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using the `array` environment and placing `\hline`s where necessary. The second, fourth, sixth and eigth row may look a bit strange at first, but they really are just empty array entries. Similarily, the third and fifth row are just `I_{11}` and `Q_{11}` with two empty array entries on either side.

Enclose it in `\left(` and `\right)`  to make it look like a matrix.

You will also need the `amsfonts` package for the Fraktur M if you haven't loaded it already.

```
\[
    G_{24} := \left(
        \begin{array}{ccccc|c} % vertical line between fifth and sixth column
            1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 & 0\\
            \hline
            & & & & & 0\\
            & & I_{11} & & & \vdots\\
            & & & & & 0\\
            \hline
            0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 1\\
            \hline
            & & & & & 1\\
            & & \overline Q_{11} & & & \vdots\\
            & & & & & 1\\
        \end{array}
    \right)
    \in \mathfrak{M}^{12}_{24}(Z_2)
\]
```