# tikz node position with auto but not center

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I wish to use auto but want the text at the center between the annotation point.it seems the align=center doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\annL}[6] [] {
    \coordinate (AE1) at ($(#2)!#4!90:(#3)$);
    \coordinate (BE1) at ($(#3)!#4!-90:(#2)$);
    \coordinate (AE2) at ($(#2)!#5!90:(#3)$);
    \coordinate (BE2) at ($(#3)!#5!-90:(#2)$);
    \draw[red,<->]  (AE1) -- (BE1) node[midway,sloped,auto,align=center] {#6};
    \draw[very thin,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] (#2) -- (AE2);
    \draw[very thin,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] (#3) -- (BE2);
}
\newcommand{\annC}[6] [] {
   \coordinate (AE1) at ($(#2)!#4!90:(#3)$);
    \coordinate (BE1) at ($(#3)!#4!-90:(#2)$);
   \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=#5},xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt]
          (AE1) -- (BE1) node [black,midway,sloped,auto,yshift=#5]  {#6} ;              
}
%
\tiny\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{>=latex}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,2);
    \draw[black,thick] (A) -- (B);
   \annL{A}{B}{1mm}{2mm}{line arrow};
    \annC{B}{A}{1mm}{2mm}{curly bracket};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

I know above and below will work fine but I wish to use auto then we can use the same command for A to B and B to A case (up and down annotation).

Comment: `align=center` doesn't do what you seem to think it will do (read the description in the manual, essentially same as adding `\centering` at the start of the node). Does adding `anchor=center` or `anchor=base` instead of `align=center` help?

Comment: using `anchor=center` or `anchor=base` has effect, if it is placed an the last place of node options (after `auto`). But then the `auto` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Zarko Well, it does what it is supposed to do ;). But `base` is better here or `south` is what I'd use. Either that or increase the shift. @OP Basically `I wish to use auto but want the text at the center between the annotation point.` makes no sense. You cannot have your cake and eat it.

Comment: Combining `auto` and `sloped` will not work because `auto` chooses a anchor first and then `slope` rotates the node.

Comment: This is [another way to see this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236399/51022).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your text is always with your brace, this is a good chance to define a new decoration that combines two predefined decorations: `brace` and `text along path`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{brace with text}{brace}
{
  \state{brace}[width=0pt,next state=text]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfqpoint{.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.3\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    {\pgfqpoint{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    {
      \pgftransformxshift{+\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      \pgfpathcurveto
      {\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{-.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.7\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{0\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      \pgfpathcurveto
      {\pgfqpoint{.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.7\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    }
    {
      \pgftransformxshift{+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      \pgfpathcurveto
      {\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{-.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.3\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    }
  }
  \state{text}[width=0pt,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgftransformxshift{+\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \ifdim\pgfdecoratedangle pt< 90pt
      \pgfnode{rectangle}{south}{\pgfdecorationtext}{}{\pgfusepath{}}
    \else\ifdim\pgfdecoratedangle pt>270pt
      \pgfnode{rectangle}{south}{\pgfdecorationtext}{}{\pgfusepath{}}
    \else
      \pgftransformrotate{180}
      \pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\pgfdecorationtext}{}{\pgfusepath{}}
    \fi\fi
  }
  \state{final}
  {}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach\i in{1,...,10}{
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace with text,text=my text}](\i*36:1)--(\i*36+60:3);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```